# Redirect wildcard route in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, url-routing

In deploying a new NextJS app there are some legacy routes that need to be preserved from the old, non-NextJS site.

`/const-string-[long-unique-hash]` is used currently for a httpd conf redirect:

Ex. `RewriteRule ^const-string-(.*)$ https://google.com?q=const-string-$1 [L,NC]`

How can I preserve NextJS routing, but allow for legacy routes matching the path: `/const-string-*`?

Desired behavior:

1. `/blog` routes `pages/blog.js`
2. `/const-string-a1b2c3d4` routes to `https://google.com?q=const-string-a1b2c3d4`

Current behavior (only localhost testing so far):

1. `/blog` routes `pages/blog.js` works as expected
2. `/const-string-a1b2c3d4` routes to `404`

How can I catch urls matching this string before it's redirected to 404?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow is not a free coding service; therefore, it’s expected that you [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question by including a [minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We advice to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks @acarlstein. I'm not expecting free coding. Just direction on a corner case. Legacy site works with httpd rewrites (as identified above). But the nextjs app redirects these to 404. My question is how to catch this before 404?

Comment: Have a look at this, you can basically control where re route the user from _error.js https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#customizing-the-500-page

Answer (score 0):

For others that may wish to do the same, I ended up using a custom 404.js file to handle redirects like this.

`pages/404.js`:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
export default function Custom404() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [route, setRoute] = useState('');

  var regex = new RegExp(/const-string-([0-9A-Za-z-]+)/gi);
  var matches = route.match(regex);
  useEffect(() => {
    setRoute(router.asPath);
    window.location.href = (matches ? "https://google.com/?q=" + matches[0] : '/?404');
  }, [router, matches]);

  return <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
}
```